# Nodejs unable to post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I am very new to programming and am following a tutorial to learn.

I am stuck and am unable to post new entries using the code and am unable to find what am I missing here. 
Any help will be appreciated.

When I am trying to post using postman, I am getting a Validation error, and when I am trying to get values I am getting [].

Edit: Error Msg: "msg":" Error: ValidationError: first_name: Path `first_name` is required., last_name: Path `last_name` is required., email: Path `email` is required."}

```js
// importing modules

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

const route = require('./routes/route');

//connect to mongoDB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/contactlist');

//on connection
mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
  console.log('Connected to database mongoDB @ 27017');
});

//on error
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Error in DB connection' + err);
  }
});

//port no
const port = 3000;

//adding middleware
app.use(cors());

//body - parser
app.use(bodyparser.json());

//static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//routes
app.use('/api', route);

//testing server
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('cutard');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started at port:' + port);
});
```

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Contact = require('../models/contacts');


//retriving contact
router.get('/contacts', (req, res, next) => {
    Contact.find(function (err, contacts) {
        res.json(contacts);
    })
});


//add contact
router.post('/contacts', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    let newContact = new Contact({
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email

    });

    newContact.save((err, Contact)=>{
        if (err) {
            res.json({ msg: ' Error: '+err});
        }
        else {
            res.json({ msg: 'Contact added successfully' });;
        }
    });
});

//delete contact
router.delete('/contact/:id', (req, res, next) => {
    Contact.remove({ _id: req.params.id }, function (err, result){
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
 });



module.exports = router;
```

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');



const ContactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const Contact = module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);
```

Comment: can you show the url are you using to post contract??

Comment: http://localhost:3000/api/contacts

Comment: The validation error comment and the lack of values strongly suggest that the issue lies not with the routing logic but rather with the request body itself. Can you please post your  Mongoose Schema for Contact and the parameters you are posting in Postman?

Comment: thats good! what is validation error are you getting??

Comment: contacts_schema
const mongoose = require('mongoose');



const ContactSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const Contact = module.exports = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);

Comment: Validation Error :

{"msg":" Error: ValidationError: first_name: Path `first_name` is required., last_name: Path `last_name` is required., email: Path `email` is required."}

Comment: parameter: 
Header: Key: Content-Type, Value: Application/json
Body: raw:  {
 "first_name":"Bruce",
 "last_name": "Wayne",
 "email":"bruce@wayne.com"
}

Comment: Use let and const instead of var please. It's 2020

Comment: Show us the error message perhaps. Put it in the question instead of a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your `req.body` there are obviously no values.

Can you confirm that your body you send in postman looks like this?

```
{
    "first_name": "xxx",
    "last_name": "yyy",
    "email": "zzz"
}
```

Also its very important to have `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`. Postman will add it automatically, if you choose JSON as format:

[image: json]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the installation of body parser.

```js
npm link body-parser
```